# Seq2Seq for prediction of complex states

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

**My problem**:
I have a sequence of complex states and I want to predict the future states.

**Input**:
I have a sequence of states. Each sequence can be of variable length. Each state is a moment in time and is described by several attributes: [att1, att2, ...]. Where each attribute is a number between an interval [[0..5], [1..3651], ...]

The example (and paper) of Seq2Seq is based on that each state (word) is taken from their dictionary. So each state has around 80.000 possibilities. But how would you represent each state when it is taken from a set of vectors and the set is just each possible combination of the attributes.

Is there any method to work with more complex states with TensorFlow? Also, what is a good method do decide the boundaries of your buckets when the relation between input length and output length is unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest a rephrasing and splitting of your question into two parts?  The first is really a general machine learning/LSTM question that's independent of tensorflow:  How to use an LSTM to predict when the sequence elements are general vectors, and the second is how to represent this in tensorflow.  For the former - there's nothing really magical to do there.

But a very quick answer:  You've really just skipped the embedding lookup part of seq2seq.  You can feed dense tensors in to a suitably modified version of it -- your state is just a dense vector representation of the state.  That's the same thing that comes out of an embedding lookup.

The [vector representation tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/word2vec/index.md) discusses the preprocessing that turns, e.g., words into embeddings for use in later parts of the learning pipeline.

If you look at [line 139 of seq2seq.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/seq2seq.py#L139) you'll see that the embedding_rnn_decoder takes in a 1D batch of things to decide (the dimension is elements in the batch), but then uses the embedding lookup to turn it into a batch_size * cell.input_size tensor.  You want to directly input a batch_size * cell.input_size tensor into the RNN, skipping the embedding step.

Comment: I indeed missed the part about embedding.
So with this  method, you assume that the each state represented by a vector, is the same vector you would find when using embedding?

Comment: Well, it's not "the same" -- but the goal of embedding is to take a very sparse space (words -- if you think about it, identifying which word it is is an 80,000-entry vector with all zeros and one one) into a much more dense space, such as a dense vector of 8 floats, or whatever, that can be operated on more easily by the RNN.  It also has the benefit - with the right embeddings - of turning semantically similar words into numerically similar vectors.  You already have a dense vector of features, so you can just directly feed that into the RNN.